# Custom repository, this user in symfony2

Tags: symfony, doctrine, repository

How you can access to the context user (i.e.: $this->getUser()) from inside a repository?

Something like:

```
public function findInviteRequestByUser(\Fundacity\UserBundle\Entity\User $user)
{
    $contextUser = $this->getUser();   
    ...
    // HERE GOES THE QUERY
    ... 

    return $query->getResult();
}
```

Comment: not directly. what are you gonna do exactly?

Comment: I'm doing a "send invitation" :), so what i need to do is set the user who is inviting (contextUser) and set a user who is going to be invited. This also has a lot of columns involved that may change, so i'm implementing an EAV model.

Comment: I would think about when you want to send this invitation and implement an event. In this way you can e.g. send an email to the recipient. Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you should pass security context as an argument.
Your controller

```
$securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
$em->getRepository('YourBundle')->findInviteRequestByUser($securityContext);
```

Your entity repository

```
public function findInviteRequestByUser(\Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext $context)
{
    $user = $context->getToken()->getUser();   

    ... 
}
```

Comment: This works, but is no way that this is defined by the class as an attribute?, something like the dependency injection but for repositories :D

Comment: well this is DI for repositories. If you want `$user` to be an attribute, just define it and call with `$this->user` in your repository